# Javascript Regex for data masking

Tags: regex, data-masking

I've been trying to figure out how to specifically mask certain parts of the string.

For example, if I were to mask first four letters in an email:

```
alias12@gmail.com => ****s12@gmail.com
```

and

mask four numbers before the last four numbers of a phone number:

```
+15123452345 => +151****2345
```

What would each of these regex expressions be using replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first one, just match the start of the string and 4 more `.`:

```
^.{4}
```

For the second one, use this:

```
.{4}(?=.{4}$)
```

This matches 4 `.` until it sees that after it, there are 4 more `.` followed by the end of string.

Comment: Can you tell how can replace all matching with X

Comment: You should do some research about the regex API of your language first. @Anuragpareek it will tell you how to do replacements.